# Wireless mouse device not working

Tags: mouse, wireless-keyboards

I have a wireless mouse It does not work in Ubuntu. It does work in Windows on the same laptop.

How can I make this wireless mouse also work on Ubuntu (16.04)?

dmesg | grep -i usb

```
[    0.200441] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.200458] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.200468] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.200480] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.139963] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.140131] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.156985] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.157036] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.157057] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.157059] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.157060] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.10.0-28-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.157061] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.157270] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.157499] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.157520] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.157747] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.158941] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.158942] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.158944] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.158945] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.10.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.158946] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.159173] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.161035] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.161064] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.161066] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.161067] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.161068] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.10.0-28-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.161069] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.161224] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.485015] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.489013] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.630232] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=a107
[    1.630235] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.630236] usb 2-1: Product: eGalaxTouch EXC7910-1018-13.00.02
[    1.630237] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: eGalax Inc.
[    1.636727] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    1.636729] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.636882] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.637724] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.637725] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.748975] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.894263] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=248a, idProduct=8367
[    1.894266] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.894267] usb 2-4: Product: Wireless Receiver
[    1.894268] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Telink
[    1.905406] input: Telink Wireless Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/0003:248A:8367.0002/input/input7
[    1.965472] hid-generic 0003:248A:8367.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Telink Wireless Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[    1.965672] input: Telink Wireless Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.1/0003:248A:8367.0003/input/input8
[    2.020969] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.025148] hid-generic 0003:248A:8367.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Telink Wireless Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
[    2.238137] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=174f, idProduct=1487
[    2.238139] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    2.238141] usb 2-5: Product: Lenovo EasyCamera
[    2.238142] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Lenovo EasyCamera
[    2.238143] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: Lenovo EasyCamera
[    2.361013] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.503017] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3004
[    2.503019] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.503021] usb 2-6: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    2.503022] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[    2.503023] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
```

out put of dmesg | tail -20

```
[   67.045722] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   67.045723] usb 2-6: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   67.045725] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[   67.045726] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
[   67.159373] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   67.159378] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   67.159383] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1055.144672] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1055.315707] do_general_protection: 12 callbacks suppressed
[ 1055.315710] traps: GUsbEventThread[1624] general protection ip:7f8885070bed sp:7f886fffdd40 error:0
[ 1055.315715]  in libc-2.23.so[7f8884fef000+1c0000]
[ 1058.214516] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1058.358893] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=248a, idProduct=8367
[ 1058.358896] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1058.358897] usb 2-4: Product: Wireless Receiver
[ 1058.358898] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Telink
[ 1058.363803] input: Telink Wireless Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/0003:248A:8367.0004/input/input16
[ 1058.422863] hid-generic 0003:248A:8367.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Telink Wireless Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[ 1058.424792] input: Telink Wireless Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.1/0003:248A:8367.0005/input/input17
[ 1058.483212] hid-generic 0003:248A:8367.0005: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Telink Wireless Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
```

Answer (score 1):

After inserting the receiver, take a look at:

```
dmesg | grep -i usb
```

or

```
dmesg | tail -20
```

to see if it logged any significant errors. Post them here if not sure.

Comment: Hi Above I Already showed the output of dmesg | grep -i usb I now also added dmesg | tail -20

Comment: Install solaar via synaptic and you should be good to go!